# inner Join not returning all rows

Tags: sql

I’m building a blog engine in C# Webforms and I have the following code that selects all blog posts that are current, meaning they should be displayed and a count of all comments for each blog post and it works great.

```
SELECT PostID, PostTitle, PostDate, PostTeaser, Count(CommentID) AS CountOfCommentID, PostCurrent 
FROM TBLBlogPost 
    INNER JOIN TBLBlogComment ON PostID = PostCommentFK 
GROUP BY PostID, PostTitle, PostDate, PostTeaser, PostCurrent
HAVING PostCurrent = 'True'
```

The problem is it only selects blog posts that have at least one comment.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for. And besides, this question has nothing at all to do with C#!

Comment: *Tricky SQL Statement* -> Posts a question about two tables with a one-to-many-optional relationship. Not sure if trolling...

Comment: @ta.speot.is Agreed, but everybody has a certain level of experience, so maybe this is tricky to the OP. Still, a better title could have been had :)

Comment: The title should have been to left or not to left, or maybe to inner or not to inner. If I had known the answer that would have been the title but I did not. I do now thanks to Justin below! Everyday more and more people are going to join this site and won’t know what it’s about. Maybe a short course is needed?

Comment: That is the job of those with experience to point newcomers to the [faq], especially the [ask] section.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a LEFT JOIN then, instead of the INNER JOIN

```
SELECT PostID, PostTitle, PostDate, PostTeaser, Count(CommentID) AS CountOfCommentID, PostCurrent 
FROM TBLBlogPost 
    LEFT JOIN TBLBlogComment ON PostID = PostCommentFK 
GROUP BY PostID, PostTitle, PostDate, PostTeaser, PostCurrent
HAVING PostCurrent = 'True'
```

`INNER JOIN` means that the matching table MUST match or else it will not fill the resultset. A `LEFT JOIN` means that if the match is not made, it will fill everything from that table with `NULL`

[Here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) is a good visual representation of the different SQL joins.

Comment: Thanks Justin, LEFT join was the answer and thanks for the description also, it was very helpful and opened my eyes to some more SQL issues I could have done better in the past. cheers